# How do I ensure that a Visualforce page opened in a custom console component scrolls to the top?

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, custom-console-components

I open a VF page in a right sidebar custom console component. If the contents fill the vertical space available, the page opens scrolled to the bottom. How do I ensure that it will instead scroll to the top?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by creating a JS static resource with a function preventPageScroll:

```
function preventPageScroll() {
  setTimeout("scroll(0, 0)", 300);
  setTimeout("scroll(0, 0)", 500);
  setTimeout("scroll(0, 0)", 800);
}
```

and then on any custom console component where content may fill the window vertically, we reference the function:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/24.0/integration.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.InteractionUtils}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  preventPageScroll();
```